# Angular Datepicker - Change the date range selection style

Tags: css, angular, datepicker

I use dateClass to highlight the time range (this range is not selectable! I just get the start and end dates and when I open the calendar I highlight the range between them)

ts:

```
 RangeClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Moment> = (cellDate, view) => {
        if (view === "month") {
            const date = cellDate.toDate();
            return date >= mystart && date <= myend ? "range-class" : "";
        }

        return "";
    };
```

css:

```
.range-class {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

html:

```
<mat-datepicker [dateClass]="RangeClass" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

This is how I see it: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC9vw.png)

I want to change the selection style to something like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp3eC.png) or [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2NUM.png)

How can I do it?

Comment: Please specify what is the style you need 2 or 3?

Comment: image 3 in priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style 1

```
.mat-calendar-body-selected {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.mat-calendar-body-in-range::before {
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfqwce-6p2zyv)

---

style 2

```
.mat-calendar-body-in-range .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

.mat-calendar-body-range-end > .mat-calendar-body-selected {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
.mat-calendar-body-range-start > .mat-calendar-body-selected {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfqwce-6p2zyv)

Second one is hard you can fine tune it yourself, but the basic layout is done!

Comment: Thanks!. But where should I apply these styles? I can only use my "range-class" style from *.ts

Comment: @Stranger you need to put the styles in the  style.css file of angular, if you want you can add a parent class to all these styles, if you want to apply them only to some datepickers, if you want to apply to all datepickers use it directly in styles.css

Comment: @Stranger Does this answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes. I haven't been able to apply the styles yet, but I think I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Stranger Use the provided stackblitz as reference, its the same as your angular project, if styles are not applied, try adding !important